# Java Spring MultipartFile when upoloading multiple files controller sees only the first file

Tags: java, spring, jsp, file-upload, multipart

Please help me with this problem. I am trying to upload up to 3 files from jsp file but the controller only sees the first file.
Here is the scholarships.jsp file:

```
<form method="POST" action="/scholarships" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="scholarshipSubmissionForm">
<div class="small-12 medium-4 columns copy-padding">
    <input class="imageUploadValidation" id="uploadImage_01_01" type="file" name="files" />
    <input class="imageUploadValidation" id="uploadImage_01_02" type="file" name="files" />
    <input class="imageUploadValidation" id="uploadImage_01_03" type="file" name="files" />
</div>
```

Here is the ScholarshipController.java:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/scholarships", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String handlePost(@RequestParam("files") MultipartFile[] files, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
     for (MultipartFile file : files) {
        // some code here
        // files array has only 1 element in it, even when I upload 3 files
     }
}
```

The problem is that `files` array has only 1 element in it, even when I upload 3 files. Am I missing something?

Comment: Interestingly your same code works perfectly for me, it is returning 3 files in any case. What configuration do you have for multipart in Spring config file and web.xml?

Comment: After doing more research and looking at my spring version I found out the problem. I was using an old Spring version. Thanks for verifying it @NisheshPratap !

Answer (score 3):

For those who ran into the same issue - make sure your Spring version if newer than 3.0.4